# Adapt embedded linux distribution to unsupported hardware board

Tags: embedded-linux, hardware

I need to adapt embedded linux distribution to an unsupported hardware. Actually im working on an embedded linux distribution.

Im lost from where to start. My question is, what factors should I consider before starting the configuration.

Im guessing drivers should be first on the list but Im not sure.

Can you help me to find a starting point and list the points and what should I pay attention for?

Kind regards

Comment: It's mot bearable task for one person (except if one is a crazy student / etc who just do it for months). Good luck!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"unsupported hardware"*?  Presumably the arch and SoC are supported, and the typical custom board is merely some modifications applied to a reference design.  That reference board (and its SDK) would be your starting point.  Read the documentation in the source code.  U-Boot describes how to "add a board" to its source code in its README file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the starting point, you won't be able to carry him all alone.

Probably you need to modify the first stage bootloader, adapt u-boot, the kernel drivers, the device tree, ...

You could use something like Yocto, but again, I don't see any chance that you will solve it all at your own.
Currently my company adapts Yocto to a new developed board, with a team of 15 people.